# Self Adjusting Javascript Countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

Is there a way to create a countdown timer using javascript that will automatically adjust to a different countdown once it reaches 0? (Example: countdown from current time until New Year of 2012 and once it reaches 0 it will change to a countdown to a birthday that is in March) (this could be used as a countdown for a schedule for an event. you could have a schedule and a countdown to the next part of the schedule once it finishes counting down to the first part)

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeForNextFunction = false;

function firstFunction(){
    //set timeForNextFunction = true when its time for the next function.
};
function nextFunction(){};

var tick = 100; //milliseconds
document.setInterval(function(){
      if (timeForNextFunction)
          nextFunction();
      else
          firstFucntion();
}, tick);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array of `Date`, for example:

```
function newDate(seconds){
    var d=new Date();
    d.setTime(new Date().getTime()+1000*seconds);
    return d;
}
var events=[newDate(10),newDate(40)];
```

And then

```
var currentEvent=0,
    cntdwn=document.getElementById('seconds');
    refreshEvent();
var timer=setInterval(display,1000);

function display(){
    var seconds=Math.ceil((events[currentEvent].getTime()-new Date().getTime())/1000);
    if(seconds>=0){
        cntdwn.innerHTML=seconds;
    }else{
        if(currentEvent<events.length-1){
            currentEvent++;
            refreshEvent();
        }else{
            clearTimeout(timer);
            // Finished
        }
    }
}
function refreshEvent(){
    document.getElementById('currentDate').innerHTML=events[currentEvent];
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/epUG4/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, out of many countdowns, you can try [jCounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter) and set its fallback to launch another instance of the plugin with another date.

This how you'd do it in jCounter:

```
$('.counterClass').jCounter({
  date: '31 december 2012 23:59:59', 
  format: 'dd:hh:mm:ss', // display days, hours, minutes and seconds, you can choose here what to display
  fallback: function() { $('.counterClass').jCounter({ // fallback for the next countdown
    date: '31 march 2013 00:00:00', 
    format: 'dd:hh:mm:ss', // format
    fallback : function() { alert("Happy Birthday!") } // second fallback
  }); }
});
```

Take note that jCounter relies on server-side timezone, the default is 'Europe/London', you can change it by adding (among the other settings), timezone: 'Europe/Oslo', or whatever you please.